# Method returns NoneType object

Tags: python, class, object, oop, nonetype

### Classes and Objects in Python

I'm creating a bot in *discord.py*, and I have a class which stores all the information related to the user, like name, settings, preferences etc. When I try to get the name of the user by calling the `user.get_name()` method(defined below), the method prints out the name and then returns a NoneType object as well! Why?

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)

user = User("Mike")
```

When run, the program prints:

> Mike
> None

How does this happen?

Comment: you have to write return and the self.name after, if no return statement is defined the default return is None.

Comment: Oh yeah of course! Thank you, that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `return` in `get_name` method,

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)
        return self.name 

user = User("Mike")
```